# SQLite3 conditional insert?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database with multiple tables.

```
table1 (Row1, Row2)
table2 (Row1, Row2)
table3 (Row1, Row2)
```

I'd like to insert data from a specific column from table 2 if and only if that specific row data exists in table 2. Otherwise not perform the action.

I considered the following:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO
    table3
VALUES
    ( x,
      ( SELECT SUM(Row2)
        FROM Table2
        WHERE Row1=y
      )
```

Thus it would stop on a conflict. But I need to insert or replace instead.

Is there some way to insert the data only if there exists some condition from another table/row?

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT ... VALUES ...` statement inserts exactly one record.

To be able to insert more or fewer records, replace the `VALUES` part with a query that returns the appropiate number of colums:

```
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT x,
       SUM(Row2)
FROM Table2
WHERE Row1 = 'y'
GROUP BY Row1;
```

(Here, the `GROUP BY` ensures that no record is returned if there is no `y` in Row1.)